# Bluetooth not working on Acer E3-111

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, bluetooth, acer

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 running as the sole OS on the hard drive, with kernel version 3.13.0-61.100-generic. System Testing tells me it has a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565 Wireless Subsystem on-board. I've turned Bluetooth on and made it visible but it does not detect devices nor can it be detected by others. The Wi-Fi is active. Pressing Fn-F3 does not turn wireless functions on or off. Is this a driver issue or something else?

EDIT: Jeremy, Here's the result from the query. Was this what you were looking for?

```
lsusb; dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ii  linux-firmware   1.127.14  all  Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
```

EDIT #2: Recently upgraded to 14.04.3 LTS. Bluetooth will only send files not receive them; the computer shows up as "ubuntu-0" to other devices. The Wi-Fi attempts to connect but fails. The Fn-F3 wireless switch is still inactive. Can this be fixed by editing configuration files?

EDIT# 3: Wi-Fi is working (must have been a bad day for wireless) but Bluetooth still is not connecting properly, if at all.

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/657917/edit) your question to include the results from `lsusb; dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware`